# Using jinja sql variables in dbt_utils

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt, dbt-utils

In my dbt project, if I declare a jinja sql variable how can I pass it to a **`dbt_utils`** function?

For example this doesn't work:

```
{% set exclude_columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"] %}

SELECT {{ dbt_utils.star(from=ref('table'), except=exclude_columns) }}
FROM {{ ref('table') }}
```

If I manually add columns to the "except" parameter, it works, but not with the variable. I tried `{{ exclude columns }}` as well and same result.

Comment: it looks right to me! can you try using `{{ log }}` ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/log/)) before the select statement? I'd be interested to see if the variables are stored correctly. something like this: `{{ log(‘nema’s exclude_columns’ ~ exclude_columns, info=true) }}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but defining a variable in my dbt_project.yml and then referencing that variable works for me!

```
{% set exclude_columns = var('exclude_fields') %}
```

```
{{ dbt_utils.star(from=ref('my_table'), except=exclude_columns) }}
```

You can also check that exclude_columns is working with this log statement:

```
{{ log(exclude_columns, info=true) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add quotation marks around the column names, otherwise Jinja will treat them as variables and fails silently, so the results will be a list of 3 `None`.

```
{% set exclude_columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"] %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my actual case, I used quotes and this still doesn't work. Updated syntax in question.